# How to sort list (PHP-Array) of countries in Chinese simplified language ('alphabetically')-> in Radical-Stroke Order?

Tags: word-order, stroke-order

I have to sort a country list (written in PHP programming language as an associative array in the order `'xy' => 'name of country',`) in simplified Chinese language to make sense for Chinese people.

So, what for the English language is alphabetic order, is for Chinese the Radical-Stroke Order. So far so good...

Is there a tool to sort them in the correct sense for Chinese people?

Comment: Lets call the array id key and the array content value. Do you want to sort by key or by value?

Comment: Do you have an ordered list of the Radical-Stroke Order? I think you would need a system similar to ASCII code. You can use "XINHUA ZIDIAN".

Comment: If you want an "ordered list," that's usually done stictly by number of strokes.

Comment: I've asked a friend from China. He sorted it for a coffee ^^

Answer (score 0):

PHP's standard `sort` ought to do the trick. It probably uses the unicode order ([Read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_orders#Computer_sorting)).

Comment: That's not going to work.